# Java android custom dialog button does not fit

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I create a custom dialog, but no all buttons fit good. I don't know why is happen , on preview in android studio is look good but in phone is not look good.

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wybierz grupę:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
       />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/fd_valSp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/fd_valSp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />


        <Button android:id="@+id/add_group_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_new_group"
             />

        <Button android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuIQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wybierz grupę:"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <Spinner

        android:id="@+id/fd_valSp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fd_valSp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_group_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_new_group" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout_weight with Linear Layout like 0.3, 0.4,0.3 this will fit buttons in it.

Or you can display 3 buttons vertically also if string is lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use weight property with linear layout, It will work for you.